# zeromq based log4j appender not closing socket

Tags: java, log4j, zeromq, appender

So I'm having some troubles with creating a custom log4j (1.2) appender.
https://github.com/stuart-warren/logit

Basic test case:
https://gist.github.com/stuart-warren/6750331

It logs over the network fine, but at the end of execution the application doesn't actually finish, I have to click terminate in Eclipse...

I'm extending the usual AppenderSkeleton that most network based appenders appear to use, but the `close()` method never appears to get called and hence I never destroy my socket.

It's probably something really obvious I haven't spotted, but I'm pretty new to java and after 2 days of tinkering it's getting to me.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

Typical, I finally work out that you have to call `LogManager.shutdown();` and that calls the appenders `close()` method successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typical, I finally work out that you have to call `LogManager.shutdown();` and that calls the appenders `close()` method successfully.

I also created a shutdown hook to close the socket if the app `exit(0)`s
https://github.com/stuart-warren/logit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stuartwarren/logit/log4j1/ShutdownHook.java